# Nginx location and try_files in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to configure nginx vhost for application and stucked.

App is in directory /site/verb

At this moment app have this kind of links and it is working:

http://example.com/verb/lt.php?some_args=some_args&some_args?some_args

What I need? I need add another link for my clients like below:

http://example.com/v/lt.php?some_args=some_args&some_args?some_args

It is only change from /verb to /v but I want to handle both (for compatibility reasons) with all arguments after .php extension.
Is it possible in nginx config? (I want to avoid creating symlinks in directory).

I tried symlinks but it is not good solution.

Comment: Hi qtop. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't forget to read the "How to ask" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article that will provide you a good understanding on what to include in your posts to help us give you the best possible answer. Can you share your nginx configuration?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply. Yes I can but I did thi by myself at the weekend.

    location /v/ {
        rewrite ^/v/(.*)$ /verb/$1 last;
    }
This works fine for me :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full server block if possible for better readability.